# Selecting rows with multiple primary keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I want to select employee with user_id 1 from organisation 3 and employee with user_id 2 from organisation 4. This is how I currently go about writing the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees AS employee
WHERE employee.user_id IN (1, 2)
  AND WHERE employee.organisation_id IN (3, 4)
```

This is the result I'm trying to get:

```
user_id   | organisation_id
1         | 3
2         | 4
```

But this is what I'm getting:

```
user_id   | organisation_id
1         | 3
1         | 4
2         | 3
2         | 4
```

How can I write my query to achieve this?

Comment: could you please post a relevant excerpt from the database (table `employees`)?

Comment: Simply translate "(user_id 1 from organisation 3) OR (employee with user_id 2 from organisation 4)" to SQL.

Comment: @jarlh while that would work, I imagine there could be X key pairs and it would become tedious

Comment: @sophros the employees table has 4 rows as in my actual result from the query (user_id, organisation_id) [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
SELECT * 
from employees
WHERE (user_id,organisation_id) IN ((1, 3),(2, 4))
```

Comment: Seems like it's pointing me in the right direction, though I'm getting error `input of anonymous composite types is not implemented`. Could depend on something else, looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

your where condition is wrong

Your goal is based  on this condition

```
SELECT * 
from employees AS employee
WHERE ( employee.user_id  = 1 and organisation_id = 3) 
OR (employee.user_id  = 3 and organisation_id = 4)
```

the IN clause you used is equal to

```
SELECT * 
from employees AS employee
WHERE ( employee.user_id = 1 OR employee.user_id = 2 )
AND  (employee.organisation_id = OR  employee.organisation_id = 4)
```